# Bootstrap (CSS) - Overlay One Img over another using responsive design

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

What CSS do I need to use so that one img "under construction" is overlayed in the top left corner of the 1st image. The section of script this pertains to is the second column in the row. I've tried various solutions using position in css but have come up with nothing that is consistent with page resizing. I need a responsive solution.

```
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2 class="text-center">Current Conditions</h2>
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Img/weather4.png")" id="current-weather-logo" class="img-responsive center-block" />
        <p class="text-center">View the current weather conditions in relation to Crestwood Assets</p>
        <p class="text-center">
            <a href="@Url.Action("CurrentWeather","Home")" class="btn btn-primary"> Launch <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
            <a href="@Url.Action("CurrentConditionsDoc","Home")" class="btn btn-primary disabled"> Documentation <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
        </p>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2 class="text-center">Historical Weather</h2>
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Img/weather4.png")" id="current-weather-logo" class="img-responsive center-block" />
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Img/under-construction.png")" id="under-construction" class="img-responsive center-block img-overlay" />
        <p class ="text-center">Leverage historical weather data for analysis with asset data.</p>
            <p class ="text-center">
                <a href="@Url.Action("HistoricalWeather","Home")" class="btn btn-primary"> Launch <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("HistoricalWeatherDoc", "Home")" class="btn btn-primary disabled"> Documentation <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
            </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
I modified to include the images in a div and provided some additional CSS.

```
<div id="img-container">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Img/weather4.png")" id="current-weather-logo" class="img-responsive center-block" />
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Img/under-construction.png")" id="under-construction" class="img-responsive center-block img-overlay" /> 
</div>




.img-overlay{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:3;    
}

#img-container{
position:relative;   
}
```

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I attempted to fit it using the top and left attributes:

```
.img-overlay{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:14.5%;
z-index:3;  
}
```

This worked great at my initial width but when sized down to a smaller window it is pushed in. I would like to be consistent.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you port your code to a site like http://jsfiddle.net in order to create a reproducible demo of where you've gotten so far? If so, it will be easier for people on the site to assist you. Working with dynamic server-side code like these Razor calls to images is difficult since we don't have access to your production base.

Comment: Try with left:0 as in my example and that should work.

Comment: You where correct, your css worked. I had to add the same max-width of the image and give it the same boot stap class center-block to ensure it remained responsive! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to put a picture above another picture: http://codepen.io/ruchiccio/pen/ZWZEEy

More than that I can't help because you haven't supplied normal paths to images so we can't see what should go onto what. Maybe provide a screenshot of what you'd like.

```
<div id="container">
 <img id="pic1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
 <img id="pic2" src="http://placehold.it/150x50">
</div>

#container {
  position: relative;
}

#pic2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will modify my question to include a screen shot as well as some code I used based of of your suggestions.